# Exporting multiple Photo Attachments from single feature with ArcPy

Tags: export, batch, attachments

How do I output a file with a counter for multiple attachments to one feature?  Below works very well for me but only for one attachment per feature.

```
import arcpy
 from arcpy import da
 import os
 
 #Modify the following to the desired location
 inTable = r"C:\"
 fileLocation = r"E:\"
 
 with da.SearchCursor(inTable, ['DATA', 'MANHOLENUM', 'Status']) as cursor:
     for item in cursor:
         attachment = item[0]
         filenum = str(item[1]) + "_"
         filename = filenum + str(item[2]) + ".jpg"
         open(fileLocation + os.sep + filename, 'wb').write(attachment.tobytes())
         del item
         del filenum
         del filename
         del attachment
 del cursor
```